# Is there an explanation as to why a 2D array is declared in such a manner?

Tags: multidimensional-array, notation

When we want to allocate memory to an `int` datatype variable, we write `int var_name`. Now if we want to allocate a 1D array of 3 `int`'s, i.e. 3 of `int` variables in a contiguous memory, we would do `int a[3]`. I was trying to make sense of why is this notation designed in such a way. So what I came up as a logical explanation was "writing the '3' was signifying that "hey, I need a variable named `a` which stores 3 `int`'s." As a notation to make sense, I would draw an arrow from 3 to the `int` saying "`a` is a variable which can store 3 `int`'s." But I am now confused with the declaration of a 2D array. Say `int arr[3][4]`, I tried to go on with the logical explanation I had deduced, meaning "hey, `arr` is a variable that gives me 4 single arrays, which are themselves of size `3`. (The last number being the indicator as to "how much" is being allocated"). But this is completely opposite of what really happens. So was this designed logically, or just a notation which is to be followed? TIA.

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: At least for C, I think it's the "logical" consequence of array declaration being somewhat inverted in the first place: `int arr[3]` defines an array of "type" `int[3]` named `arr`. (Compare `int *arr`, which looks closer to being a variable of the `int *`, although the `*` is still "associated" with the name, not the type.) `int arr[3][4]` is similar: the "outer" part is `int ... [4]`, with `arr` being something that holds 3 values of type `int .. [4]`.